# Pandas fillna not successfully replacing nan values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Attempting to fill na values in the following manner:

```
df['column'].fillna(value='value',inplace=True)
```

I print the values before and after and get the following results:

```
['11', '12', '81', '21', '22', nan, '41', '71', '10', '23', '02', '20', '19', '72', '24', '53', '60', '49']

[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
['11', '12', '81', '21', '22', nan, '41', '71', '10', '23', '02', '20', '19', '72', '24', '53', '60', '49']

[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]
```

Clearly  the values are being identified as NaN values, but the fill not is not filling the nan floats.

Quick note - unsure why but when I dropped the inplace = True in my code, the code worked as intended. Regardless, the answer pinned should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
value = 9999
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce').fillna(value).astype(int)
```

Or

```
value = '9999'  # a string
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('nan', value).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    column
0       11
1       12
2       81
3       21
4       22
5     9999
6       41
7       71
8       10
9       23
10       2
11      20
12      19
13      72
14      24
15      53
16      60
17      49
```

Comment: This does look like a viable work around - my main concern is why this is an issue in the first place since I don't want to be so reliant on specific fixes, if that makes any sense. Is there a way to ensure these values are treated as regular nans/why are they not being?

Comment: Your data are clearly not identified as NaN values but as strings so you can't use `fillna` because `'nan' != np.nan` How do you create your column?

Comment: If you accept to convert as float, you can also use: `df['column'].astype(float).fillna(9999)`.

Comment: The data that initially comes in has an issue where the blank columns are filled with "". I then replace them with a regex "\"\" and replace the value with np.nan. The nan values in the example are floats (see further down the list) which is why I am confused

Comment: `df['column'].fillna(value:'value',inplace=True)` is not a valid python code. What do you try exactly? (`SyntaxError`)

Comment: apologies - my code is now updated but is as follows:
df['column'].fillna(value='value',inplace=True)
value: 'value' was intended to have an equal sign

Comment: Ok. Your code works well for me. From your second list, I used your code and `nan` is replaced by `'value'`.

Comment: Truly very odd - I dropped the inplace and it appears to work in my code now. I am so very uncertain why....  data be weird is my best guess XD